# Proving that a particular order is impossible

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

A friend shared this puzzle with me on Discord:

> There are 5 bowls, labelled 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. The bowls can only be moved around in pairs without changing the order of the pair. The bowls can also be inserted between other bowls. For example, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 can become 3, 1, 2, 4, 5 by moving 1,2 in between 3 and 4.
>
> Assume that the starting position is 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.
>
> Prove that it is impossible to reach the position 5, 2, 3, 4, 1.

My initial intuition was invariance of some sort but I have no idea how to even start. Would appreciate some thoughts!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! If this is a puzzle you found somewhere else, you need to provide attribution to the original source, partly to prevent plagiarism and partly to ensure that this isn't from an ongoing competition.

Comment: @F1Krazy Hello, the source is discord, my discord friend challenged me to solve this puzzle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with many classic permutation puzzles, this depends on the invariant called

> permutation parity. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation))

Every move is

> an even permutation, because if you move the pair of bowls one at a time instead of as a pair, it can be seen as doing the same cycle permutation twice. Any sequence of moves is therefore also an even permutation.
>  The final goal position is an odd permutation, because it is exactly one swap away from the starting position (a swap of 2 and 4), and one is an odd number.

Therefore the goal cannot be reached using moves alone.